# Sorting NSDictionary keys by NSNumber value

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, nsdictionary

I have some NSDictionary like this:

```
@{
@"some key":{
    @"notImportantKey":@"asdasda",
    @"weight":@1
},
@"some key 2":{
    @"notImportantKey":@"asdasda",
    @"weight":@2
},
@"some key 3":{
    @"notImportantKey":@"asdasda",
    @"weight":@3
},
@"some key 4":{
    @"notImportantKey":@"asdasda",
    @"weight":@4
}}
```

I need array of keys (some key, some key2,...), sorted by weight value.

Comment: Ok, I had typo in NSDictionary :) There is now 4 different keys. I don't want to order nsdictionary, I just need to get allKeys into NSArray, ordered by weight.

Comment: Good edits, removing downvote.

Comment: Because are originally written, it was terrible.  Your edits improved the question, and as such I removed the downvote.  I commented on removing the downvote to encourage other downvoters to remove their downvote as well.

Comment: Thanks guys for fast and correct answers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSArray *keys = [dict keysSortedByValueUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary *obj1, NSDictionary * obj2) {
    return [obj1[@"weight"] compare:obj2[@"weight"]];
}];

NSLog([keys description]);
```

Comment: Cool. I did not know about the `keysSortedByValueUsingComparator:` method. And I thought I know Cocoa's container classes pretty well...

Answer (score 2):

This is what `keysSortedByValueUsingComparator:` is for. It compares the values at the dictionary and gives you the order the keys would be in if they were sorted using those values. For example:

```
[yourDictionary keysSortedByValueUsingComparator:^(NSDictionary *a, NSDictionary *b) {
    return [a[@"weight"] compare:b[@"weight"]];
}];
```